# Solr - Return word NGrams, even with mixed word order

Tags: n-gram

I haven't been able to find a resource which explains a means by which I can return the most common word NGrams which do not depend on word order, and have flexible word position boundaries.  I think this concept is analogous to having slop in the results, as opposed to having slop in the query.

For instance, I understand a typical BiGram or CommonGram may allow for indexing the following text: "The quick brown fox..." 
As these terms: "The quick" "quick brown" "brown fox"... 
And from there, it shouldn't be a problem if I simply want a request handler or facet which will return the top 100 (or so) most frequently occurring word BiGrams.

But here are two cases that concern me:
1) If, in my corpus, I see occurrences of "quick brown" and "brown quick" - they will be counted separately.  For my purposes, these may be related, so I'd like them to be counted as one.
2) If, in my corpus, I see occurrences of "quick fox" and "quick brown fox" - they will be counted separately.  For my purposes, I would like to see "quick fox" double-counted in this case.  In reality, this case is a simplification - the terms "quick" and "fox" may be separated by several words.  (This may be obvious, but, I can't simply run a slop query for those two terms and return matching documents because I don't know those terms are.)

To elaborate (Jan's question) if "quick fox, quick fox" appears in a a document, I would ideally like the word pair "quick fox"/"fox quick" to be counted as:
 - appears three times if separated by 0 words ("quick fox" x2, and "fox, quick" x1)
 - appears five times if separated by 1 word (the above, plus "quick..., fox" and "fox, ...quick")
 - appears six times if separated by 2 words (the above, plus "quick..., ...fox")

Also, for the text: "quick quick fox fox", I would ideally like the word pair "quick fox"/"fox quick" to be counted as:
 - appears once if separated by 0 words ("quick fox")
 - appears three times if separated by 1 word (the above, plus "quick ... fox" x2)
 - appears five times if separated by 2 words (the above, plus "quick ... ... fox")

(Although my example here is showing two words, my question is a little more broad than just two-word combinations.  But if all I had were two-word combinations, I'd be more than happy with that.)

The reason "why I care" is that I work in the (incredibly imprecise) industry which merges technology and services/support.  I have an existing application with Solr that I want to add a new feature to - this feature would allow users to mine the text data terms which may be related by some sort of flexibly-defined proximity.  To elaborate - the users have a several queries already, which run sequentially, and the results plot on a graph.  The users then:
a) begin manually reading through documents that match each query
b) try to identify terms or phrases which are common
c) subdivide and refine their queries
d) re-plot the results of the queries
e) repeat, starting with a)
I would like to provide them these "sloppy word NGrams" almost like a word cloud, so the users can get immediate feedback to subdivide and refine their queries while developing them, without having to open and read through the documents.

I understand that the [TermVectorComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent) will allow me to get back all the position and frequency information of individual terms I care for, and from there I could probably do whatever I want - but I'd rather not have to do that if I don't need to.

Ideally, I would like whatever solution there is to respect stopwords.  (That is, in the above example, simply don't index: "The quick" at all if "the" is a stopword.)

Lastly, I am not well versed in the capabilities of document summarization, or search suggestions, or some of those other concepts that I consider "advanced" given how new I am to this.  If what I just described can be provided by one of those features, please let me know and I'll read up on them more.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to count pairs of words occurring in a document which are separated by any number of other words? What happens if some words occur multiple times: How often counts "fox quick" in "quick fox, quick fox" and how often in "quick quick fox fox"?

Comment: Yes, pairs, or even potentially three or so words that occur in some proximity to each other.  I'll modify the original post to elaborate.

Comment: Also - I would like to get these counts per field (I have several multi-valued fields which each represent a single sentence, and I would at minimum like the length of those fields to be the maximum bounds of this counting.)  If I need a count per paragraph, or per document, etc. I can always just make another multi-valued field and count in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got what you want to achieve. It's not too difficult but hardly performant.

I will only sketch my idea, as I'm lying in my bed and will not provide Java-code without my IDE :-)

Basic principle is you create your own Tokenizer (in fact your own filter, but as it will create a lot additional tokens, it feels more like a tokenizer) that you chain after your favorite Tokenizer-Filter-Chain (lowercasing, stopword filters, synonyms, umlaut filtering)

I assume that N in your N-grams has a maximum (otherwise you need to load the whole field to memory) And I assume further, that there is a maximum distance `M` of the two outmost tokens in an N-gram with `M>=N`

1. Load a FiFo-Queue of size M with the first M token from your tokenizer chain.
2. do

   1. Now build all Bi to N-grams with the first token (N-1 bigrams, …, 1 N-gram)
   2. order each alphabetically and return each single n-gram as token
   3. pop the first token
3. while (push the next token from tokenizer to queue OR queue not empty)

For performance reason, implement the Fifo as Ringbuffer-array.
This will give you an index with all n-grams where you can simply count them.

When you need the offset later, store it as payload or use it to set a weight to the tokens.

Let's do an example:

```
input="quick brown fox jumps quick fox"
N=3
M=4
```

First filling of the buffer with tokens "text":position:weight

```
buffer = ["quick":1:1,"brown":2:1,"fox":3:1,"jumps":4:1]
```

will create the following bi-gram tokens ( I use the weight to store the reciprocal distance between the two outmost original tokens such that weight 1 means no intermediate tokens)

```
"brown quick":1:1,"fox quick":1:0.5,"jumps quick":1:0,333
```

and the 3-grams:

```
"brown fox quick":1:1,"brown jumps quick":1:0.5,"fox jumps quick":1:0.5
```

popping first buffer element and fill with next

```
buffer = ["brown":2:1,"fox":3:1,"jumps":4:1,"quick":5:1]
```

doing the N-grams

```
"brown fox":2:1,"jumps brown":2:0.5,"brown quick":2:0,333
"brown fox jumps":2:1,"brown fox quick":2:0,5,"brown jumps quick":2:0.5
```

If look now at the index, we can already see, that several N-grams occur multiple times:

```
"brown quick"↦:1:1,:2:0,333
…
"brown jumps quick"↦:1:0.5,:2:0.5
…
```

continuing

```
buffer = ["fox":3:1,"jumps":4:1,"quick":5:1,"fox":6:1]
```

I assume, that you are only interested in n-grams of different words, so I filter duplication in N-grams:

```
"fox jumps":3:1,"fox quick":3:0,5
"fox jumps quick":3:1
```

now reaching the end of input we just reduce the buffer

```
buffer = ["jumps":4:1,"quick":5:1,"fox":6:1]
"jumps quick":4:1,"fox jumps":4:0,5
"fox jumps quick":4:1

buffer = ["quick":5:1,"fox":6:1]
"fox quick":5:1
```

Comment: Since I'm a total newbie (never programmed in Java before), this will take me some time to process.  Some questions:
1) Are you assuming all the words I want to remove will be in the stopwords?
2) When you say "chain after your favorite tokenizer(s)" - I understand there is only one tokenizer, and several filters.  Did you mean "chain after your favorite tokenizer/filter(s)"?  I use the default field type text_en_splitting, so I'm not sure if I replace WhiteSpaceTokenizer with mine (which calls WhiteSpaceTokenizer), or if I add my tokenizer somewhere in after the WhiteSpaceTokenizer.

Comment: I put some more details in the answer: 

1) Yes, that is what a stopword list is for.

2) create a new Filter and add it to the existing filter chain. You need to go beyond default arguments

I suggent you index your n-grams into a separate field

Comment: I added an example algorithm execution to the response

Comment: @TimmTheEnchanter I think I have to mention you, in order that you get informed …